# Prisma update operation failing in validator; using generated `UncheckedUpdateInput` type instead of `UpdateInput` type

Tags: prisma

I'm trying to perform an update operation:

```js
  const specialItem = await db.specialItem.update({ where: query, data: formattedUpdate })
```

The value `formattedUpdate` in that statement looks something like this:

```js
{
  item_name: null,
  drink_type: 'Wine',
  price: 800,
  bar: {
    connect: {
      id: '4486bbc3-5ff8-47c8-99cf-9291c57ebe78'
    }
  },
  event: {
    connect: {
      id: undefined
    }
  },
  related_item: {
    connect: {
      id: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

This operation fails in the Prisma validator with the errors:

```
[1] Unknown arg `bar` in data.bar for type SpecialItemUncheckedUpdateInput. Did you mean `id`? Available args: ...
[1] Unknown arg `event` in data.event for type SpecialItemUncheckedUpdateInput. Did you mean `event_id`? Available args: ...
[1] Unknown arg `related_item` in data.related_item for type SpecialItemUncheckedUpdateInput. Did you mean `related_item_id`? Available args: ...
```

However those fields are most definitely in my schema:

```
model SpecialItem {
  id                  String      @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  created_at          DateTime    @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(3)
  event               Event?      @relation(fields: [event_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  event_id            String?     @db.Uuid
  bar                 Bar         @relation(fields: [bar_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  bar_id              String      @db.Uuid
  related_item_id     String?     @db.Uuid
  related_item        Item?       @relation(fields: [related_item_id], references: [id])
  is_recurring        Boolean     @default(false)
  is_inactive         Boolean     @default(false)
  ...
}
```

The available args the error suggests comes from the generated Prisma type `ModelNameUncheckedUpdateInput`, however I believe this operation would succeed if it were using the generated Prisma type `ModelNameUpdateInput`. **The *unchecked* version uses IDs directly, where as the *regular* version uses the connect object pattern.** I'd prefer using the latter. Why is Prisma expecting me to satisfy the unchecked version of the type? Can I force the validator to use the regular version?

Has anyone run into this before? I don't think it makes sense to break from the connect pattern I use elsewhere.

Using Prisma version 4.9.0.

I've tried searching, ChatGPT, the github, read the docs, and no cigar.

Comment: Do you experience the same behaviour in Prisma version 4.8.1?

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue. Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @EkanshSaxena I just posted my answer to this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to remove all undefined connections from the update object:

```
import { forEachKey } from '../helpers'

/**
 * Deletes fields that start with __
 * According to Prisma, undefined fields don't do anything.
 * To unset a field, pass the value as null.
 * These fields are used to describe a field that needs to be connected.
 */
export default function deleteUndefinedConnections(params: object) {
  forEachKey(params, key => {
    const val: any = params[key]
    if (typeof val !== 'object') return
    if (val === null) return
    if ('connect' in val) {
      if ('id' in val.connect && (typeof val.connect.id === 'undefined' || val.connect.id === '')) {
        delete params[key]
      }
    }
  })
  return params
}
```

The operation would succeed after.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try modify your code to get this result:

```
{
  item_name: null,
  drink_type: 'Wine',
  price: 800,
  bar: {
    connect: {
      id: '4486bbc3-5ff8-47c8-99cf-9291c57ebe78'
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure, but look like Prisma will use `Unchecked` type if there are `undefined` in nested fields

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wasn't passing any `undefined` value but it was a mix of `id` field and `relation` fields, for example if the relation is `Vendor` then id field for that was `vendorId` similarly `UpdatedBy` and `updatedById`.

Payload which gives error

```
{
  name: "some name",
  updatedById: <some_uuid>,
  Vendor: {
    connect: {
      id: 2
    }
  }
}
```

Payload which works fine:

```
{
  name: "some name",
  UpdatedBy: {
    connect: {
      id: <some_uuid>
    }
  },
  Vendor: {
    connect: {
      id: 2
    }
  }
}
```